# SharedPreferences listener not working when called from class

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to clean up my code and make a class which will be only used for SharedPreference changes.

This is what I currently have:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
    }

    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
            // listener implementation
            if (key.equals("listEventType") || key.equals("listEventAge")) {
                recreate();
            }
        }
    };

}
```

This one is working great. However, as soon as I move this code to my support class:
package com.example.rok.terroristinfo;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class SharedPreferencesInit {
    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    public SharedPreferencesInit(Context context, Activity activity) {
        this.context  = context;
        this.activity = activity;
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    protected void recreateOnChange() {
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener( new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
                // listener implementation
                if (key.equals("listEventType") || key.equals("listEventAge")) {
                    activity.recreate();
                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```

And call it from MainActivity class as:

```
new SharedPreferencesInit(getBaseContex(), this).recreateOnChange();
```

it is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: what's the error?logcat?

Comment: Nothing special in logcat. No errors or anything. Everything I know is, `recreateOnChange` method isn't called.

Comment: Have you tried debugging in order to be 100% sure that is not executed?

Comment: Oh my god I'm stupid. Tried again with Toasts. `recreateOnChange` is called, however, `onSharedPreferenceChanged` method inside listener is not called. Maybe something with context I pass into class and SharedPreferences aren't stored as they should be?